# resolving pack uri not working in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uri, resourcedictionary

Although I've found a lot of "pack uri issue" questions, I didn't get an answer for my problem.

I have a prism solution where I want a `MyApplication.Resources` assembly hold all my application wide styles and templates.

So

- Step 1: I've created the solution (WpfUsercontrollibrary)
- Step 2: folder /Themes was created
- Step 3: Generic.Ribbon.xaml was created
- Step 4: Generic.xaml was created
- Step 5: Generic.xaml has a MergedDictionary part to merge all the
  Generic.xxx.xaml files
- Step 6: MyApplication.Resources assembly referenced in prism module
  assembly
- Step 7: loading the Generic.xaml in my module view (type:
  ***Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonTab***

  ```
  <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApplication.Resources;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
  ```

I've also tried the absolute variant with

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ElairoCRM.Resources;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
```

All steps above are verified with the [MSDN doku to pack uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-EN/library/aa970069.aspx) and a lot of stackoverflow questions and wpf resource tutorials in the internet.

But nothing works. Did I miss something?

Thank you in advance.

***Edit:***
I've forgot the error that occured:

> XamlParseException with inner exception FileNotFoundException having the message:
>   The file or assembly \"MyApplication.Resources, culture=neutral" or one of its dependencies, was not found.

Comment: the link you added does not work (goes to Page Not Found)

Comment: note that this question has been asked by OP [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/58e5d975-2246-4efa-878a-50dc16c817ac) as well

Comment: The link is working fine for me. But MSDN has some long loading times since yesterday for me. Maybe it's a MSDN problem. I've added some additional informations.

Comment: I've been looking on microsoft docs as I'm having the same issue in my own application. I'd like to use an external library to hold my resource dictionaries. That way a suite of software all made with the same UI could reference the same libraries. Pretty sensible structure. This was working as described in the MS docs article I found prior to .NET 5 but hasn't worked for me since. Everything looks correct here at first glance so it could be the same issue I'm having and more or less looks like it is.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem by myself. I copied the Generic.xaml file in the Resource assembly from the themes folder to the assembly root and changed the pack argument to component/Generic.xaml. Everything works now as expected. I've found no documentation about this behaviour.